# What's the syntax for filter inventory using facts in Ansible Tower?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, ansible-tower

I tried different combinations with no luck.

Filter by Ubuntu version:

```
ansible_facts.ansible_distribution_version:"14.04"
```

Doesn't work

```
ansible_facts.ansible_distribution:Ubuntu
```

working fine

That's mean is possible filter by OS but not from OS version.

I also tried using `variables:something`

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty way to do the same, filtering by release version according to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

ansible_facts.ansible_distribution_release:trusty

I don't know how to filter using version number.

Any ideas?

Comment: save all variables in file - `ansible -m setup hostname >> outputfile` and you can see need variable